# How to pass efficiently a subvector of std::vector<cv::Point3f> as parameter (don't own function)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use an opencv function that accepts `std::vector<cv::Point3f>` among other parameters. In my program, I have an `std::vector<cv::Point3f> worldPoints` and another `std::vector<int> mask`, both of larger dimension than what I want to send.

What I want to do is pass to the opencv function only the entries that have a respective non-zero mask, as efficiently as possible.

```
std::vector<cv::Point3f> worldPointsSubset;
for (int i=0; i<mask.size(); i++) {
    if (mask[i] != 0) {
        worldPointsSubset.push_back(worldPoints[i]);
    }
}

// Then use worldPointsSubset in function
```

Is there any other way around, possibly involving no copying of data?

EDIT 1: The function I am referring to is [solvePnPRansac()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga50620f0e26e02caa2e9adc07b5fbf24e)

Answer (score 1):

The function that you call requires a vector of `Point3f`, so if the only thing you have is a masked vector, then you have to copy the data first. There is no way around this if the function doesn't accept a vector and its mask.

To see if this copy is an issue, you must measure the drop in performance first and see if this copy is a bottleneck. If it is a bottleneck, the first thing is to count the number of points you need and reserve that capacity in `worldPointsSubset`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to convert data from `std::vector<int>` to `std::vector<cv::Point3f>` without a copy because despite the fact you see the same values the size of data might be different.

But you can change the type of data you are working on (`std::vector<int>` to `std::vector<cv::Point3f>`) and work directly with `cv::Point3f` and when needed pass it to `solvePnPRansac()`.